# How to reset form validation in Formik using Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I use Formik and Yup in my React front-end. The form renders bunch of DOM elements based on a list selection on the form so for example if users select option A, it renders say Name, Address, if user selects option B, it renders say their license and permit details. Each of these segments on a single Form has it's own validations which are independent of each other. So, if user selects option A, the form performs all option 'A' related validations and if it passes, you see the submit button enabled.

My problem is once all validations are passed for one option, the SUBMIT button gets enabled though if user changes their mind and select another option from the list say option B, the SUBMIT button is still enabled. I expect the form validation to reset as now the option has changed which needs a new set of validation. How do you achieve this?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Hi @Joel, here is the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-germain-p0nwor?file=/src/changeRequest.jsx .. the checkRequestType() function show\hides form elements.